# Error busqueda entre fechas SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, busqueda-rango-de-fechas

tengo unas tablas con la siguiente estructura(en todas las tablas el tipo de datos de FechaHora es char(26) menos en una tabla que es varchar(255)):

| ID | FechaHora |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 28/01/2022 |

La consulta que hago es la siguiente:

`SELECT * FROM RT_Registros0 where TimeString >='23/02/2022 13:54:53'and TimeString <='28/02/2022 08:48:40`

Y el resultado que me da es incorrecto, me aparecen fechas con el dia 23 hacia adelante.
He probado tambien con BETWEEN y tampoco me funciona. No funciona en ninguna tabla.

Comment: Prueba con el siguiente formato: 2022-02-23 13:54:53 , es decir aaaa-MM-dd hh-mm-ss

Comment: No me ha funcionado, me ha aparecido el resultado sin registro.

Comment: Pero dices que el tipo es "TimeString" ??? Que yo sepa no existe ese tipo, o es Datetime o es string (ej: varchar) y si es el último ahí está el problema

Comment: Si, disculpa, es tipo char(26).

Comment: Cuando uso el siguiente codigo 
`select GETDATE() ` me devuelve esta cadena("2022-09-26 14:56:36.450") no se si tendra algo que ver con la configuración.

Comment: Lo que seguramente te pasa es que el string que tú tienes guardado es incompatible con el casteo (es por esto que no se deben guardar datetimes como string), porque el formato (el orden del año, mes y día) no está bien. Entonces tienes que encontrar la manera de indicarle el formato al CAST. Yo borré mi respuesta, porque esa parte no sé cómo hacerla, ya que nunca me he visto en esa situación

Comment: El problema es que no estás buscando entre fechas, estás buscando entre cadenas de caracteres que podrían ser interpretadas como fechas. Lo primero que debes hacer es corregir tus tablas para que te ahorres futuros problemas de rendimiento y programación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que más te va a servir es usar el operador <kbd>**CONVERT**</kbd> ya que puedes ayudarte de los formatos de `DATETIME`; para mucha más 'seguridad' en caso de fallo usa el <kbd>**TRY_CONVERT**</kbd>.

Uso el formato 103 porque es el que se usa mayormente en la región:  `DD/MM/YYYY`.

```sql
select try_convert(datetime,fechaHora,103) fechaHoraRenov
from(
  values('28/01/2022 20:04:05'),('24/01/2022 18:40:56'),
  ('23/01/2022 05:06:11'),('23/02/2022 08:05:01'),('23/02/2022 13:54:53'),
  ('23/03/2022 13:00:03'),('15/02/2022 14:01:05'),('29/03/2022 19:04:40'),
  ('23/07/2022 13:01:00'),('10/01/2022 13:50:01'),('09/02/2022 15:30:01'),
  ('14/03/2022 20:00:01'),('08/01/2022 15:40:00'),('28/02/2022 08:48:40')
  ) x (fechaHora)
where try_convert(datetime,fechaHora,103) >= 
      try_convert(datetime,'23/02/2022 13:54:53',103)
  and try_convert(datetime,fechaHora,103) <= 
      try_convert(datetime,'28/02/2022 08:48:40',103)
```

Resultando la siguiente tabla como respuesta:

```sql
+--------------------------+
| fechaHoraRenov           |
+--------------------------+
| 2022-02-23 13:54:53.000  |
| 2022-02-28 08:48:40.000  |
+--------------------------+
```

> Probar <kbd>**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/hwkI-kfU)**</kbd>

Comment: Hola @BrianON, yo lo intentaría con  `where CAST(fechaHora AS datetime) BETWEEN  CAST('23/02/2022 13:54:53' AS datetime) AND CAST('28/02/2022 08:48:40' AS datetime)`. Si no es necesario especificar horas y minutos entonces `where CAST(fechaHora AS date) BETWEEN  CAST('23/02/2022' AS date) AND CAST('28/02/2022' AS date)`